# No title in Amazon SNS GCM push notification

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Amazon SNS console to send android mobile push notification. I did receive push notification but only the body message is displayed, the title is not displayed.Also when the notification was touched the app was not opened. I am using Amazon AWS SDK for Unity.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: {
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Hi\", \"title\": \"TestTile\" } }"
}
in Amazon SNS Console

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html

Comment: I followed docs and so only i am receiving push.Also  i am using unity3D not java eclipse android.But when the notification was clicked the app is not opening.

Answer (score 3):

It would be great if you share some code, but as i understand you want to receive push with title and body message, so you have to retrieve it first.

When you receive push intent in your Service you should call intent.getExtras().getString("title"). And if you want to open app when you click on push notif you should set it up in your notification Intent.

Here is a simple example how to do it:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (!extras.isEmpty() && messageType != null) { 
        switch (messageType) {
            case GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR:
                Toast.makeText(this, GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED:
                Toast.makeText(this, GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE: // retrieve your data here
                Log.d("onHandleIntent", "Message= " + extras.getString("message"));
                Log.d("onHandleIntent", "Title= " + extras.getString("title"));
                sendNotification(extras.getString(message), extras.getString(title));
          }
    }
    PushBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg, String title) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); // activity wich you want to open when click on push notification
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_TAG, msg);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_TITLE_TAG, title);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Jarik  said you would have to do that.

Also assuming youre facing the same problem i did, create a jar file whose class extends the gcm listener or whatever class the callbacks work with(dont remember the name right now,  open their class file and you will find the java classes extending the gcm receivers), and  then use intent for the notification touch that would open the application.  Also this would let you use the title functionality.  I found that somehow in amazon sns sdk class files,  they have overwritten the title with a ""  hence the title always seem to be blank.

Dont forget to put UnityPlayerProxyActivity in the Android manifest.